# bootstrap 4 right menu on small device

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to put logo image on left and nav on right in xs devices 
and logo image on center and nav on left from sm devices.
with my code nav don't align to right in xs

The problem is: how align nav on right in xs devices?

```
<div class="container-fluid border-bottom">
<div class="row d-flex align-items-sm-center">
<div class="col-6 col-sm-2 logo pt-2 pb-2 text-sm-center order-sm-2"> <img src="myimage.png"> </div>
<div class="col-6 col-sm-5 order-sm-1">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav"> <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> <a
                class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Azienda</a> <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Prodotti</a> <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled"
                    href="#">Cataloghi</a> </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="d-none col-sm-block col-sm-5 order-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'd use the responsive flexbox util classes `justify-content-end justify-content-sm-start`...

```
<div class="container-fluid border-bottom">
    <div class="row d-flex align-items-sm-center">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-2 logo pt-2 pb-2 text-sm-center order-sm-2"> <img src="//placehold.it/130x40"> </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-5 order-sm-1">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light justify-content-end justify-content-sm-start">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav align-items-sm-start align-items-end"> 
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Azienda</a> 
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Prodotti</a> 
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Cataloghi</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none col-sm-block col-sm-5 order-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/R04RL0gbbH

Comment: Perfect is just what I was looking for

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved.